# Can I Prevent `numpy.array` Converting List of Arrays into Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, numpy

If my input arrays have different shapes, `np.array` returns a one dimensional array of arrays. E.g.:

```
>>> np.array([np.zeros(8), np.zeros(9)], dtype=object)
array([array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])], dtype=object)
```

However, if the arrays are of the same shape they get joined and a multidimensional array is returned:

```
>>> np.array([np.zeros(8), np.zeros(8)], dtype=object)
array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=object)
```

Is there a way to force the equivalent shape case to behave as the nonequivalent?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can't think of any advantage in not having a multi dimensional array?

Comment: Create an object dtype array, and copy the list to it.

Comment: The array's are not equal by rule, they would only ever be coincidentally equal so the application code expects 1 dimension.

Comment: @SuperShoot In this case, I would use a Python list instead of a NumPy array of arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj That's the solution I'm running with, just curious as to whether there was a better way. What if I didn't know how many array's there would be?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a `list`, not a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @liliscent I'm passing this to a cython function and using the memory view of the array. You are right though, a list would work but I'm curious that the constructor would behave inconsistently without a way to coerce consistent behavior.

Comment: Numpy arrays are intrinsically designed for representing matrices and the object type is only useful when item types are not the same and generally is there for the sake of comprehensiveness. As mentioned you should us a Python list in such cases but if still you don't have access to the whole program and/or don't want to break the compatibility of your functions/modules you can [create your own numpy-array object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) that handles such cases.

Comment: Thanks @Kasramvd, makes perfect sense.

Comment: An object dtype array contains pointers to arrays elsewhere in memory.  So for many purposes it is more like a list than a numeric array.  The main array benefit is that it can be reshaped.  I don't know how it behaves in `cython` as a `memoryview`.

Comment: @Kasramvd I did end up using a multi dimensional array (as you suggested in your first comment) and just sized it to fit the largest data set along axis 1 and it was _significantly_ faster. Cheers.

Comment: @SuperShoot Great ;))!